# Angular optional named groups on url leave encoded question mark

Tags: angularjs, encoding, angular-routing, named-parameters

I have the following angular route:

```
            $routeProvider.when('/sites/:var1/:var?/something/:year?/:month?/', {
                templateUrl: 'path-to-template.html,
                controller: 'PageController'
            });

             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

The problem is that when i hit the route http://www.somesite.com/sites/category/something/2014/10/ Angular   tries to match the optional named groups and in the end transforms the url to 
http://www.somesite.com/sites/category/%3F/something/2014%3F/10%3F/ and redirects me to the that path.

Does anyone knows of any good reason why the optional path would be replaces by /?/ (encoded: %3F)?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT**

What happens is that router in angular replaces the url to match exactly what you provide in the .when, in terms of / ? (and not sure what else). So if it finds a route matching .when but missing either / or ? it just appends it and refreshes (angular refresh) and then apparently url encodes it. (??? :o)

Comment: Can you post a plunker of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I've narrowed it down to the trailing slash. Using:

```
'/sites/:var1/:var?/something/:year?/:month?/'
```

together with:

```
http://www.somesite.com/sites/category/something/2014/10/
```

resolved correctly, as does removing the slash from both.
In fact, adding any optional named group to the url causes the route to be slash dependent.
As to *why* this is happening...

Comment: If i remove the trailing slash form the route it works. But that is not the problem because if i do that the inverse has a problem. What i am trying to understand is why a route without optional named groups i.e. '/something/something' (with or without trailing slash) works either way but not routes with optional named groups?